# How do I name files of images in a function then call from outside in php?

Tags: php, function, datetime, imagemagick, imagick

I have code using imagick, that imports image from a form post in another script. It then renames the file with it's new text to tmp/$timestamp.jpg in the function. That's easy it works even. How can I call that new file outside the function, or just get access to it? 
Basically I just want to paste a link to the file below where image iss posted after script is ran.

```
<?php 
function annotateImage($imagePath, $strokeColor, $fillColor) {
    $imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($imagePath));
    $draw = new \ImagickDraw();
    $draw->setStrokeColor($strokeColor);
    $draw->setFillColor($fillColor);
    $draw->setStrokeWidth(1);
    $draw->setFontSize(36);
    $text = $_POST["selfxpress"];
    $draw->setFont("/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/impact.ttf");
    $draw->setgravity(imagick::GRAVITY_SOUTH);
    $imagick->annotateimage($draw, 0, 0, 0, $text);
    header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
    echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
    $imagick->setimageformat("jpeg");
    $timestamp = date('D:H:i');
    $imagick->writeImage ("tmp/".$timestamp.".jpg");
}
if ($_POST["selfxpress"]) {
annotateImage("webcam.jpg", black, white);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure you've saved the file in a web accessible location, but otherwise if you add a return statement to the end of your function that will do it.

```
<?php 
function annotateImage($imagePath, $strokeColor, $fillColor) {
    $imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($imagePath));
    $draw = new \ImagickDraw();
    $draw->setStrokeColor($strokeColor);
    $draw->setFillColor($fillColor);
    $draw->setStrokeWidth(1);
    $draw->setFontSize(36);
    $text = $_POST["selfxpress"];
    $draw->setFont("/usr/share/fonts/msttcorefonts/impact.ttf");
    $draw->setgravity(imagick::GRAVITY_SOUTH);
    $imagick->annotateimage($draw, 0, 0, 0, $text);
    header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
    echo $imagick->getImageBlob();
    $imagick->setimageformat("jpeg");
    $timestamp = date('D:H:i');
    $fileToWrite = "tmp/".$timestamp.".jpg";
    $imagick->writeImage ($fileToWrite);
    return $fileToWrite;
}
if ($_POST["selfxpress"]) {
    $imageLocation = annotateImage("webcam.jpg", black, white);
    echo '<img src="' . $imageLocation . '" />';
}
?>
```